# Can't chain commands in jquery after find

Tags: jquery, navigation, chaining

I am creating a navbar I want it to fade in and out as the user rolls over. It is working on a 
span that is of opacity 0 to start. The navbar works fine except that it triggers twice when the page is on location. Right now I can't even chain commands in my code-see the delay. I tried eq(0) but that didn't work.

```
    $(".menu").mouseover(function(){ 
        $(this).find("span.menu-hover").delay(100).fadeTo(800,.9,function(){});
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).find("span.menu-hover").delay(100).fadeTo(400,0,function(){});
    });
```

Comment: Note that the delay is 0.1 seconds, are you sure you even see it ?

Comment: OK. looks like I need to use stop() to stop the animation. But I still cant chain commands.